# A Donald Duck version of The Odyssey

Tags: story-identification, donald-duck

I once read a comic version of The Odyssey in which the main characters were portrayed by characters in the Duck universe.

Can you help identify the story?

Here is some information:

- The story was likely published some time before 2007.
- I presume the copy I read may have been several hundred A5-pages thick and the language may have been Norwegian.
- I am fairly certain that Donald Duck plays the role of Odysseus and that Daisy Duck plays the role of Penelope. I think Gladstone Gander may have been a suitor of Penelope.
- Donald gets tied to the mast of the ship as they pass the sirens and I think he asks his crew to put cotton in his ears.
- I seem to recall a cyclope and several sheep.
- Donald gains some weight while staying with Circe. I don't think Circe was portrayed by Magica de Spell, although it is possible.
- I think one of the final scenes involves archery and tomatoes.

None of these stories look correct:

- "Oddball Odyssey" https://duckcomicsrevue.blogspot.com/2009/07/oddball-odyssey.html
- "The Odyssey"  https://scrooge-mcduck.fandom.com/wiki/The_Odyssey
- "Disney Literature Classics 17 - Donald's Odyssey"
- "Paperodissea" - Arnoldo Mondadori

Comment: https://www.lustiges-taschenbuch.de/ausgaben/alle-ausgaben/ltb-33-der-schatz-des-odysseus?

Comment: This Danish book seems to fit, except it wasn't published until 2021. Maybe the Norwegian version was published earlier? https://www.liveboox.com/produkt/jumbobog-501-pocket-9788793840416

Comment: Here's a Swedish Duck book that also seems to fit - except it, too wasn't published until 2021. https://kalleanka.se/ankeborgsposten/kalle-mystiska-myter/

Comment: A Dutch Duck Odyssey: https://comicvine.gamespot.com/donald-duck-201948/4000-753898/

Comment: A Norwegian version of the Danish book I mentioned above. http://www.minetegneserier.no/pls/htmldb/f?p=100:6:0:VIEW:NO:RP,6:P6_UTGIVELSER_ID,P6_CS:135147,79E0E412B785DD8B

Comment: Thank you for the contributions. None of the suggestions seem to be it. Both the Dutch and the Swedish suggestion seem to be in the wrong format, i. e. they are magazines and not books. The Dutch suggestion seems to have the same front page as the Norwegian nr. 38 2020. The German suggestion from @Valorum, seems too short and it looks like it and "Oddball Odyssey" are both translations of "Zio Paperone e il tesoro di Ulisse". I could check out Donald Pocket 504 as suggested, but I am not too hopeful that it is it.

Comment: danish donald duck odyssey - https://www.ebay.com/itm/325275159086

Comment: @Improve, does my previous comment ring any bells?

Comment: @shanu Thank you for the contribution. I don't recognize any of the drawings. Also, I am fairly certain that Donald was the main character, while the story you linked seems to revolve around Mickey and Goofy.

Comment: @Improve, Ok then i shall continue my research

Comment: "Donald Duck: The Odyssey" by Guido Martina and Massimo De Vita. This comic book was first published in Italy in 1994 and has been translated into various languages, including Norwegian.

Comment: @shanu I will take a closer look at this and get back to you. It looks like this book can be bought at various online shops, but I am having trouble finding pictures other than the front cover.

Comment: https://openlibrary.org/search?q=Paperodissea&mode=everything? - you can see more than the front cover there...

Comment: https://inducks.org/story.php?c=I+TL+3272-1? (or any of these;  https://parodytv.one/news/topodyssey-disney-parody-of-the-homeric-poem-is-back-in-a-de-luxe-version/#)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have made a small research, could it be in this publication of the 2005?
[Sverd og sandaler](https://inducks.org/issue.php?c=no%2FTP2005-2)

Inside I found that it has this story (which was also published earlier in Norway in the 1995), which is called
[The Adventures Of Donald Dysses](https://inducks.org/s.php?c=D%2092228)

Unluckily I haven't read the story, so I cannot say if it ticks all boxes, or if it is one of the already-mentioned stories in the question. Anyway it seems to have the characters mentioned by the OP (such as Gladstone and Magica).

Comment: I am fairly certain that this is it! I recognize the crown on Donald's head. I will try to obtain a copy of it and then mark this answer as correct.

Comment: This is it! I had conflated the storylines of Circe (Magica) and Calypso, and the crew puts parsley and not cotton in their ears (and not Donald's). Thank you so much for your efforts. Now I get to read the story again after all these years.